# Need to migrate Microsoft office outlook .pst file in to Ubuntu 14.04 ver.

Tags: server, thunderbird, email, postfix, evolution

i am migrating my system Microsoft in to Ubuntu 14.04 ver. so i have my existing .pst file how can i configure in Ubuntu ?

i have configure in Evolution mail client which is successfully configuration has done in pop after i have import my .pst file My .pst file size around 8 Gb which is successfully added after i have seen in evolution mail client all my mail which is came randomly, some mail has not come, attachment also not detected. etc..

so, another way i have saw Thunderbird mail client is available, so i have configure my mail with pop service which is successfully configure but i have no idea about how can i add my existing .pst file in to Thunderbird mail client. please give me free tool or converter available on internet please suggest. 
i believed in the Thunderbird .OST file created after configure mail.?

so, i request to you please give me solution how can i migrate my .pst in file in Ubuntu 14.04 ver.

Comment: The readability of your question could really profit if you started to use punctuation to mark where one sentence stops and the next one begins. It's a bit hard to read and understand currently...

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this would be installing Thunderbird on the Windows system where the original Outlook is installed. When running Thunderbird for the first time it asks you if it should import anything. After that is done you could just copy the Thunderbird profile to the Linux system.

See as well https://kb.mozillazine.org/Import_.pst_files and especially http://kb.mozillazine.org/Import_.pst_files#Linux where they address some solutions without using Windows or Outlook.

Comment: I used this process and it worked well.